# PHP Sub Variables

Tags: php

Im currently using session variables to store a users information but i want to change it for ease of coding to variables like $user->username

Variable im using:

```
$_SESSION['username']
$_SESSION['email']
$_SESSION['firstname']
$_SESSION['lastname']
$_SESSION['ip']
$_SESSION['level']
$_SESSION['subscriber']
```

Variables i want to use:

```
$user->username
$user->email
$user->firstname
$user->lastname
$user->ip
$user->level
$user->subscriber
```

Comment: Can you use an array? $user[newKey] = newVariableValue. Then $user['newKey']

Answer (score 7):

Just cast the array to an object:

```
$user = (object) $_SESSION;
```

From the [documentation on objects](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting):

> Arrays convert to an object with properties named by keys, and corresponding values. For any other value, a member variable named scalar will contain the value.

Comment: What about numerical array keys such as `array('aa','ba','bb');` or `array(0 => 'rr', 6 => 'vv');`?

Comment: @sємsєм you can use `$user->{"0"};`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the BEST way to handle this, but its an easy work around to dealing with arrays.

- NOTE: You really should shy from using superglobals and ESPECIALLY  the Session to store any type of user data. That information is easily obtainable from the computer and can compromise your site and users.

  class Record {
      $data;

  ```
  public function __construct(array $data) {
      $this->data = $data;
  }

  public function __get($name) {
      return $this->data[$name];
  }

  public function __set($name, $value) {
      $this->data[$name] = $value;
  }
  ```

  }

  $user = new Record($_SESSION);
  echo $user->username;

Comment: I like Tim Coopers solution much more, thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a object with a mapper

```
 class User {
       public $username;
       public $name;
       public $firstName;
       public $lastName;
       public $ip;
       public $level;
       public $subscriber;

      // add methods that would be useful on a user manipulating the above values;
      public static function createUserFromArray($array){
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = $array["username"];
            $user->name = $array["name"];
            $user->firstName = $array["firstName"];
            $user->lastName = $array["lastName"];
            $user->ip = $array["ip"];
            $user->level = $array["level"];
            $user->subscriber = $array["subscriber"];
            return $user;
      }
 }
```

Then When you want to create a user from the stored session data you would simply use:

```
 $user = User::createUserFromArray($_SESSION);
```

This will allow you to source your users from any appropriate array, this can be the session or a database result row or from an array literal.